# SwiftUI TabView not updating View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults, swiftui-tabview

My problem is that TabView is not updating.

I want to log-in and then re-render another view (Profile Screen) instead of (Login Screen) in the same `TabItem`.

The `TabView` goes to `ProfileScreen` only after i kill the app and reopen it.

Here's the `TabView` code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var userToken: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserToken") ?? ""
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            HomeScreen(text: .constant("")).tabItem({ Image(systemName: "house") }).tag(0)
            Text("Cart").tabItem({ Image(systemName: "cart") }).tag(1)
            if userToken.isEmpty {
                LoginScreen().tabItem({ Image(systemName: "person") }).tag(2)
            } 
            else { 
                ProfileScreen().tabItem({ Image(systemName: "person") }).tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Passing different @State values to both screens
- Rendering Profile Screen in LoginScreen but it renders on top of the TabView

Comment: Where are you modifying the "User Token" property?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest SwiftUI, consider using @AppStorage instead of @State:

```
@AppStorage("UserToken") var userToken: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the value of userToken in any other view, for example may be LoginView, you need a mechanism to inform the content view about that update.

You can consider using LocalNotifications here for sending the update to ContentView so that the view reloads on status update.